# View top CPU consuming thread(s) in a Java Process running inside a Docker container

Tags: java, linux, docker, shell, cpu-usage

We have a Java application running inside a docker container, which is running high on CPU. I was able to get the thread dump from the docker shell, but I am not able to view the top CPU consuming threads inside the java process.
I went into the docker shell using `docker exec -it container sh`

`top` gives me the top CPU consuming processes

I would like to see the top CPU consuming threads inside a particular PID.

`top -n 1 -H -p [PID]` does not work, and I get "top: unrecognized option: H"

Using docker top from outside the shell does not work either. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a busybox image.  Consider using another with a top you like better.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `jstack` tool from container?

Comment: I did use jstack to obtain the thread dump, but it is not giving me enough info to find out which thread is consuming a lot of CPU. And for that, I was looking to use top to get the top CPU consuming threads from the java PID.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using some lightweight linux images (e.g alpine etc). I couldn't find why some of the top utilities doesn't have -H flag in it. But if you change your image to another linux distro like ubuntu, it will work. I'm guessing you're doing some debugging on your local machine, so it won't hurt to change the image you're using. It might be workaround for your problem.